# How to override MuiInputLabel outlined in mui 5

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am migrating from material-ui 4 to mui 5 and I want to override MuiInputLabel in theme override.

This is what I have done already is:

```
 'MuiInputLabel': {
  'styleOverrides': {
    'marginDense': {
      'lineHeight': '1.5px',
      'fontSize': typography.caption.fontSize,
    },
    'outlined': {
      'transform': 'translate(1.4rem, 0.9rem) scale(1)',
      '&.marginDense': {
        '&.shrink': {
          'transform': 'translate(15px, 0px) scale(1.05)',
          'fontSize': '11px !important',
        },
      },
    },
}}
```

I have tried changing the names of the props, but something is off, although the root styles are being applied but the outlined object's `transform` property is what I want to be applied.

In the current scenario the `outlined` and `marginDense` are not being applied but if I put them inside the `defaultProps` object the `MuiInputLabel-outlined` class appears in DOM but I cannot see the styles for it in the browser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If anyone is still interested how to do this, this is how it should be done:

```
    MuiInputLabel: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          fontSize: '0.95rem',
        },
        shrink: {
          transform: 'translate(14px, -8px) scale(1) !important',
        },
        outlined: {
          transform: 'translate(14px, 16px) scale(1)',
        },
      },
    },
```

*shrink* is the part where input is focus or has some value, *outlined* is the default state with empty input

Comment: Got to know about this 3 days earlier, was about to answer my own question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure it is wrapped in component. Also I dont know if this is a newer thing however shrink is not for when the input is focused its only if it shrunk due to some value...why its like that I dont know since it shrinks when you hover over it. Other for changing the color of it when focused you can use this

```
import { formLabelClasses } from "@mui/material";

  components: {
    MuiInputLabel: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          color: "white",
          [`&.${formLabelClasses.focused}`]: {
            color: "purple",
          },
        },
      },
    },
```

},